# Build Failure for iOS on Unity/Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, setup-project

I'm currently trying to set up a Unity project that's set up for VR into AR for iOS. I'm using the AR Foundation plugin + ARKit/ARCore plugins. Trying to build it and run on my iPhone using Xcode and I'm getting these errors.

Tried changing a bunch of player settings.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AREnvironmentProbeAnchor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXREnvironmentProbeProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARCollaborationData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRSessionProvider.o)
  "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      _UnityARKit_Camera_AcquireConfigurations in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRCameraProvider.o)
      _UnityARKit_Camera_TryGetCurrentConfiguration in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRCameraProvider.o)
      _UnityARKit_Camera_TrySetCurrentConfiguration in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRCameraProvider.o)
      (anonymous namespace)::ARKitXRCameraProvider::ResetLocalConfigurationState() in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRCameraProvider.o)
      (anonymous namespace)::ARKitXRCameraProvider::HandleARKitEvent(UnityARKitEvent, void*, int) in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRCameraProvider.o)
      _UnityARKit_EnvironmentProbeProvider_Construct in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXREnvironmentProbeWrapper.o)
      _UnityARKit_EnvironmentProbeProvider_Destruct in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXREnvironmentProbeWrapper.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARBodyAnchor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRHumanBodyProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRImageTrackingProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARBodyTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRHumanBodyProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageAnchor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRImageTrackingProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARSkeletonDefinition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRHumanBodyProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARObjectAnchor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRObjectTrackingProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARReferenceImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRImageTrackingProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARMatteGenerator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRHumanBodyProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARReferenceObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UnityARKit.a(ARKitXRObjectTrackingProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Perhaps a similar kind of error question was asked here. [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-when-building-samplescene-from-arfoundation-to-iphone-6s.545338/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Unity ARKit package, it requires XCode 11 and iOS 13 because they are supporting ARKit 3. I had similar issues and getting the beta for XCode and iOS got it running.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my project. (Thanks @saif for the [Unity forum link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-when-building-samplescene-from-arfoundation-to-iphone-6s.545338/#post-4805576))

**The culprit was a wrong ARkit XR Plugin version in Unity**, which tries to use features from a later AR Kit version in Xcode thus giving those errors related here.

I manage to get working within my setup (for those in 2018.4.x)

- Unity 2018.4.5f1
- AR Foundation 1.5.0-preview.6
- AR Subsystems 2.2.0-preview.3
- **ARKit XR Plugin 2.1.1 (update from 2.1.0-preview.5)**
- XCode 10.3 (building to an iOS 12.4 device)

If you are running Unity 2019.x with AR Foundation 2.x you probably want to find the correct ARKit XR Plugin as indicated [here in the AR Foundation samples on Github](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples#warning-arkit-3-support)